# What can be done if "altitude" reading is negative in sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.msg?

Tags: gps, ros, altitude

What to interpret and how to process the data in general when the values (from gps sensor) for "altitude" field in **ROS *sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.msg*** is **negative** ?

Comment: It means you’re below sea level or your sensor is wrong? Much more context is needed to give an answer here

Answer (score 0):

Even at sea level, altitude may be negative: GPS uses a mathematic earth model to  estimate the height in mean sea level. This model is usually a simplified EGM96 geoid.
The local sea level might be some meter higher or lower.

Just be aware that this is not unusual.
Depending what your app Should do, you can display any value < 0 as 0.